# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error showing on design load in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I have seen many questions on the same topic here, and tried almost all solutions recommended, But still not getting it cleared. So please kindly let me know any new updates on this.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ClinicManagement_Forms.ClinicDetails"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:view="clr-namespace:ClinicManagement_Forms"
         mc:Ignorable="d" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="875" Height="474">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <view:ClinicRegistrationViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="LeftErrorTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).[0].ErrorContent, ElementName=ErrorAdorner}" Background="LightCoral" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="ErrorAdorner">
                    <Border BorderBrush="LightCoral" BorderThickness="1" />
                </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,0,0,444" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Clinic Registration" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="873" Height="30" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Showcard Gothic" />
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="91,99,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Clinic Name" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="202,96,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Text="{Binding CliicRegistation.ClinicName , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"  Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource LeftErrorTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="91,136,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Address" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="58" Margin="202,133,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="91,210,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Place" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="202,207,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CliicRegistation.Place, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="91,250,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Phone No" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="202,247,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CliicRegistation.PhonNo , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"  Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource LeftErrorTemplate}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="True"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="91,289,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="User Name" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="202,286,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CliicRegistation.UserName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="91,329,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Password" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="202,329,0,0"   Name="passwordBox1" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource LeftErrorTemplate}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="91,367,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Confirm Password" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="202,367,0,0"  PasswordChar="{Binding CliicRegistation.ConformPassword, Mode=TwoWay ,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource LeftErrorTemplate}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
    <Button IsEnabled="{Binding CliicRegistation.AllPropertiesValid}" Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="202,441,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Button IsEnabled="{Binding CliicRegistation.AllPropertiesValid}" Content="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="299,441,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Button Content="Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="397,441,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="536,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="561,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="148" OpacityMask="#FFD44949"/>
    <Button Content="Select" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="559,207,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="5.053,-10.4"/>
    <Button Content="Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="647,208,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="5.053,-10.4"/>


</Grid>
```

It is the code I had tried, when i click on design mode, This error is shown.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that possible error could happen in `ClinicRegistrationViewModel` constructor? Can you post that too?

Comment: there is nothing in constructor, I just called an empty constructor

Comment: Is it shown on the Fifth Button from the bottom , or the second TextBlock from the top ?

Comment: There should be a stack trace available where you can find out what is actually causing the `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)